# How do I invoke a data enrichment function before model.predict while serving the model in Databricks

Tags: model, databricks, mlflow, mlops, serving

In Databricks, I have used mlflow and got my model served through REST API. It works fine when all model features are provided. But my use case is that only a single feature (the primary key) will be provided by the consumer application, and my code has to lookup the other features from a database based on that key and then use the model.predict to return the prediction. I tried researching but understood that the REST endpoints will simply invoke the model.predict function. How can I make it invoke a data massaging function before predicting?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches for that:

1. You can use [custom MLflow model](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/models.html#custom-python-models), where you override the `predict` function, and it will call database or other source for an additional information, and then call actual `predict` of the model.  You can find more information in following answers: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65887231/use-mlflow-to-serve-a-custom-python-model-for-scoring/65888860#65888860), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67786052/log-pickle-files-as-a-part-of-mlflow-run/67786986#67786986).
2. Use [Databricks Feature Store](https://docs.databricks.com/applications/machine-learning/feature-store/index.html) for your data, train & log model using the FeatureStoreClient.log_model function, then [publish feature store tables into a database](https://docs.databricks.com/applications/machine-learning/feature-store/feature-tables.html#publish-features-to-an-online-feature-store), and then [use model via model serving, and it will automatically lookup for features](https://docs.databricks.com/applications/machine-learning/feature-store/feature-tables.html#enable-databricks-hosted-mlflow-models-to-look-up-features-from-online-stores).

Comment: Thank you! This will get me started on exploring other means to the solution. I started working on FunctionTransformer to add a custom function to my sklearn pipeline to eventually use pipeline.predict.